# Delete Array if it has a element with specific value from session

Tags: php, arrays, session, laravel-4

Is it possible to / How would i delete an array element if that element is array and it has specific element? I have an array from session (I am using laravel 4).

I am using this to add it to session

```
 Session::push('answers', array('exam_id' => $exam, 'question_id' => $index, 'answer_id' => $answer));
```

And to get answers out and how i would delete them

```
$values = Session::get('answers');

 foreach ($values as $index1 => $value) { 
     if ($value['exam_id'] == $examid && $value['question_id'] == $questionid) {

             // Delete Array from session   
      }
    }
```

So for example if `$value['exam_id'] = 1` and `$value['question_id'] = 2`

From this

```
"answers":[{"exam_id":"1","question_id":"1","answer_id":"3"},{"exam_id":"1","question_id":"2","answer_id":"6"}]
```

I would like to get

```
"answers":[{"exam_id":"1","question_id":"1","answer_id":"3"}]
```

Comment: Use `unset` or reinitialize the `array`.

Comment: but if i use unset it will only delete the element from array.. I would like to delete array if one of its elements meets the if statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to delete a specific array from a multidimensional array, you can use the `unset` method, by specifying the index of the subarray which you want to delete.

```
$values = Session::get('answers');

foreach ($values as $index => $value) { 
   if ($value['exam_id'] == $examid && $value['question_id'] == $questionid) {
       unset($values[$index]);    
       break;
   }
}
```

The result would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [exam_id] => 1
            [question_id] => 1
            [answer_id] => 3
        )

)
```

Comment: Sometimes i am really stupid, i totally forgot about this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to delete the whole array itself, call forget.

```
Session::forget('answers');
```

If you need to delete the specific element of the array, I think you could combine get and set operations.

```
$values = Session::get('answers');
//...do something to $values, then
Session:put('answers', $values);
```

Comment: I have made an edit to the question as i didnt explain good. I have put an example also. I know how to delete from session but i dont know how te delete an array1 which is inside array2 by elements inside array1. Hope i explained good this time